# Longstep arrow in formula

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image: Arrow]

I want to include this kind of an arrow with a label above it. I vaguely remember it being called longstep in latex. I am unable to find any packages that have such an arrow. Can anyone help?

Comment: `\overset{r}{\Longrightarrow}` (requires `amsmath`).

Comment: As LaRiFaRi below, I'd rather recommend `\xRightarrow` from `mathtools`. This also changes the length to accommodate whatever is written above.

Answer (score 2):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}%[column sep='what-ever-unit']
\arrow[Rightarrow]{r}{r} & \null
\end{tikzcd}
$\overset{r}{\Longrightarrow}$
$\xRightarrow{r}$
\end{document}
```

[image]